# Corba non blocking orb 

Tags: java, corba

Im trying to do a Corba program implemented with java that is at the same time a server for another java  program and a client for another , so i need a non blocking orb which can be run in a separate thread (i have it in my class Orb_run) :
but i have a problem when instanciating Orb_run , i have to provide an ORB object ,but if i call init method on the orb it will create a new bkocking object here's my server's code,

```
public class machine {                                                                         
static int uid = 1;               
etat_machine etat;
static ORB  orb;   
static int token_uid  = 1;                                                                                                        


static void server(String[] args, int uid, int token_uid){         
   try {        
    //Instanciate Orb obj
    //orb = ORB.init(args, null); 

    //Instancier Orb_run
    Orb_Run orb_run = new Orb_Run(orb);

    POA poa = POAHelper.narrow(orb.resolve_initial_references("RootPOA"));
    poa.the_POAManager().activate();    

    machineImpl machine = new machineImpl(poa, uid, jeton_uid);        

    // create the object reference
    org.omg.CORBA.Object mach = poa.servant_to_reference(machine);

    try {
            String m1_ref = orb.object_to_string(mach);
            String refFile = "m1.ref";
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream(refFile));
            out.println(m1_ref);
            out.close();
            } 
        catch (IOException ex) {
                System.err.println(
                        "Impossible d'ecrire la reference dans m1.ref");
                System.exit(1);
            }

        System.out.println("Le serveur m1 est pret ");

        // wait for requests
        orb_run.run();

    System.exit(0);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }    

  //Client
  public static int client(int token_uid){

    orb.init(); 
   // Orb_Run orb_run = new Orb_Run(orb);
     String ior = null;

        try {
            String ref = "m2.ref";
            FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(ref);
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(file));
            ior = in.readLine();
            file.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.err.println("Impossible de lire fichier : '" +
            ex.getMessage() + "'");
            System.exit(1);
        }


        org.omg.CORBA.Object obj = orb.string_to_object(ior);

        if (obj == null) {
            System.err.println("Erreur sur string_to_object() ");
            throw new RuntimeException();
        }

 machine machine = machineHelper.narrow(obj); 

        if (machine == null) {
            System.err.println("Erreur sur narrow() ");
            throw new RuntimeException();
        }


        System.out.println("avant appel traitement_message ");

        jeton_uid = machine.traitement_message();

        System.out.println("le uid ds le jeton mnt"+ jeton_uid);

        return jeton_uid;
    }
```

}

I'm starting a non-blocking orb in a seperate thread using this class:

```
 public class Orb_Run extends Thread {

    public ORB  orb_;

   public Orb_Run(ORB  o) {
       orb_=o;
   }                                             
   public void run() {
      System.out.println("Le serveur est pret");
      orb_.run();
   }    }                                                                                      }
```

So if you have some tips on how to do it , it will be great .

thanks.

Comment: This is the server aspect of the program. What does the client aspect look like?

Comment: I added the client aspect and the class in which im launching the orb in another thread , i'am  confused about whether to use init method orb = ORB.init(args, null); before launching orb in another thread ?

Comment: I don't think you need to start the ORB more than once. Once should be enough for the whole JVM, containing both client and server code. I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of any way to start a non-blocking ORB using the standard APIs in Java. Can you instead spawn a new thread to run the ORB, and then carry on working in the main thread? Or spawn worker threads for the client work, and use the main thread for the ORB?

Answer (score 1):

Just don't execute the `orb_run.run();`

Since this method is for blocking the current threads....

Answer (score 0):

Still in Java 7 the ORB.run() method actually performs an infinite wait;
working thread run independent from ORB.run() .
So there is no need to call it at all and you have an excellent non-blocking ORB.